# SQL Code for Circular Reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I on looking for a sql code (preferably with joins, not with cursors or stored proc or variables).

We have a parent manager-employee relationship in a database table, where the manager erroneously becomes the employee for some of the succeeding verticals/records, Example below:

[Pic of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBFFi.png)

```
Reporting Manager   Employee
1                     2
2                     3
3                     4
4                     1   --<< Circular Reference
```

(The last record is wrong, and creates a circular reference with the first record, as 1 cannot report back to 4)

I am looking forward to find these records who pose this kind of a circular reference, any help is really appreciated.

I have attached a pic of how the data looks like.

Comment: Tag your DBMS please.

Comment: MySQL should be fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query just add a check for repeating path part.

Comment: I reckon youre talking about this one ?

SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';

Comment: No, I mean recursion. The main problem here is that there can be a number of cycles. I don't believe they all can be detected with a single query, although listing all participating pairs in all cycles is rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by joining the table to itself.  See below:

```
select b.Parent, b.Child
  from your_table a
  join your_table b
    on b.Child = a.Parent
 where b.Parent > a.Parent;
```

Comment: Thx Juveleo1906, self join makes sense, but the last where clause may not work if the field has both text and numbers, like IP001.

Comment: That's correct, unless the letters in the fields are just prefixes.  If that were the case you could just `CAST` or `CONVERT` the field and it would still evaluate correctly.  This wouldn't work if the letters are actually a meaningful part of the data.